# collapse rows, keep all unique variable values in one column and all values in other column

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize, across

I need to take this data and group all matching values in column `ESVId`, while retaining each unique value in column `match`; and all values in column `Form` that were associated with each value in column`match`(there may be duplicates!).

```
structure(list(ESVId = c("ESV_000001", "ESV_000004", "ESV_000004", 
"ESV_000004", "ESV_000004", "ESV_000004", "ESV_000004", "ESV_000004", 
"ESV_000004", "ESV_000005", "ESV_000005", "ESV_000005", "ESV_000005", 
"ESV_000005", "ESV_000005", "ESV_000005", "ESV_000006", "ESV_000006", 
"ESV_000006", "ESV_000007"), MT_species = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), match = c("Pseudotsuga menziesii", 
"Artemisia dracunculus", "Achillea millefolium", "Artemisia absinthium", 
"Artemisia ludoviciana", "Artemisia frigida", "Artemisia campestris", 
"Artemisia tridentata", "Artemisia tilesii", "Rubus arcticus", 
"Fragaria vesca", "Rosa acicularis", "Fragaria virginiana", "Rosa woodsii", 
"Rosa arkansana", "Rubus ursinus", "Poa pratensis", "Vahlodea atropurpurea", 
"Alopecurus magellanicus", "Prunus virginiana"), Form = c("Conifer", 
NA, "Forb", NA, "Forb", "Sub-Shrub", "Forb", "Shrub", NA, NA, 
"Forb", "Shrub", "Forb", "Shrub", NA, NA, "Graminoid", NA, NA, 
"Shrub")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

When I tried

```
MTTaxa_funct <- funct_esvs %>%
  group_by(ESVId) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(paste(unique(match, Form), collapse= " OR ")))%>%
  dplyr::select(ESVId, match, Form) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

it fills column `Form` identically to `match`, which is not at all what I want. I also need to keep any NA values in column `Form`.
Ideally this would come out looking like this:

```
structure(list(ESVId = c("ESV_000001", "ESV_000004", "ESV_000005", 
"ESV_000006", "ESV_000007"), match = c("Pseudotsuga menziesii", 
"Artemisia dracunculus OR Achillea millefolium OR Artemisia absinthium OR Artemisia ludoviciana OR Artemisia frigida OR Artemisia campestris OR Artemisia tridentata OR Artemisia tilesii", 
"Rubus arcticus OR Fragaria vesca OR Rosa acicularis OR Fragaria virginiana OR Rosa woodsii OR Rosa arkansana OR Rubus ursinus", 
"Poa pratensis OR Vahlodea atropurpurea OR Alopecurus magellanicus", 
"Prunus virginiana"
), Form = c("Conifer", "NA OR Forb OR NA OR Forb OR Sub-Shrub OR Forb OR Shrub OR NA", 
"NA OR Forb OR Shrub OR Forb OR Shrub OR NA OR NA", 
"Graminoid OR NA OR NA", 
"Shrub"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: (1) How does your expected output _look_ like? (2) In your shown data there is no `form` column.

Comment: whoops, thanks for pointing that out! put it back in.

Comment: Now I still don't understand, how your `Form` column should look like after the summarising.

Comment: Added desired output

Comment: Perhaps: `funct_esvs %>% group_by(ESVId) %>% summarise(match = paste(unique(match), collapse = " OR "), Form = paste(Form, collapse = " OR "), .groups = "drop")`?

Comment: Can you expand on *"all values in column `Form` that were associated with each value in column `match`"*? If `match` must be all unique values (`paste(unique(match), collapse=" OR ")`), I don't understand if `Form` should be `paste(Form, collapse=" OR ")` or something contingent on the uniqueness of `match`. Also, where do `"Prunus pensylvanica"` and `"Prunus emarginata"` come from?

Comment: I'm not sure how I should have phrased the question, but the answer you provided is exactly what I wanted. Given that, do you have a suggestion on a clearer phrasing I should have used?  
Oh, and those last 2 species were just me getting carried away when I was making my wishlist of how things should look (obviously my actual dataset is much larger than 20 rows).

Comment: Sorry @MartinGal, I honestly do not recall seeing your comment when I posted my nearly-identical answer. I didn't intend to hijack it from you.

Comment: @r2evans I'm totally fine with your answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, since your expected output has elements not present in your source data, but perhaps this?

```r
quux %>%
  group_by(ESVId) %>%
  summarize(
    match = paste(unique(match), collapse = " OR "), 
    Form = paste(Form, collapse = " OR ")
  )
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   ESVId      match                                                         Form 
#   <chr>      <chr>                                                         <chr>
# 1 ESV_000001 Pseudotsuga menziesii                                         Coni…
# 2 ESV_000004 Artemisia dracunculus OR Achillea millefolium OR Artemisia a… NA O…
# 3 ESV_000005 Rubus arcticus OR Fragaria vesca OR Rosa acicularis OR Fraga… NA O…
# 4 ESV_000006 Poa pratensis OR Vahlodea atropurpurea OR Alopecurus magella… Gram…
# 5 ESV_000007 Prunus virginiana                                             Shrub
```

Comment: this works, as does Martin Gal's answer below, which is almost the same except the ```.groups="drop"``` at the end. what does that do and why are the advantages/disadvantages to including?

Comment: (Honestly I didn't see @MartinGal's comment, I should have waited.) Depending on what work is done, sometimes the grouping remains for all or some of the group variables. `?summarize` is a good reference for it.